# What is wrong with this JPQL query string

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

```
SELECT m FROM Clientmessage m 
WHERE (((m.userid = 4) OR ( m.recipientid = 4 ))  
AND (m.isdeleted = false)  
AND ((m.currentstate IS NULL) 
OR (m.currentstate IN (NULL, 'CREATED', 'DELIVERED')))) 
order by m.timereceived
```

> line 1, column 48: syntax error at [=]. Internal Exception:
>   MismatchedTokenException(80!=82)

Any idea what the error could be ?! I m out of ideas.

So stackoverflow wants me to explain why my question is different from a possible duplicate. To be hoenst I get tired of this site. It is not, and if I have to explain this every time someone thinks I have to explain something, I look for help elsewhere. Geez.

Comment: People you got to imagine the first 6 lines are 1. That s how I originally posted them. Then they got edited.

Comment: Show us the code of the entity

Comment: Try removing the NULL from your IN(NULL,...) since you already test for it

Comment: farrellmr: yes. the redundancy null check was the reason. it shouldnt make a difference, but I gues that when the underlying jpa component will translate it into jdbc/sql, it will result in odd behavior, since redundancies in criteria are maybe not checked

Comment: What is character 48 of that query?!

Answer (score 2):

I'll post an answer so the question can be closed - the issue was the NULL in the -

```
m.currentstate IN (NULL, 'CREATED', 'DELIVERED')
```

You can use the COALESCE function similar to NVAL

Shame your question got edited, and then having to explain why a duplicate was wrong